# portlet jsp auto submit form without refresh page

Tags: javascript, jsp, portlet

In a jsp page I have this form:

```
<form name ="form1" id="form1" method="post" action=portlet:actionURL name=acao
input type="text" name="data" id="2">
```

and I use this to fil the form with data:

```
document.getElementById("2").value= lonlat;
```

I'm using document.getElementById("1").submit(); to auto submit the form but it auto refresh all the page but my intent is to auto submit without refreshing all the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on submit you need to make Ajax call and in portlet class override the serveResource

In jsp or java script you can get resource url as

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="resourceURL">  
 </portlet:resourceURL>
```

serveResource() method

```
@Override  
          public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest,  
                    ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws IOException,  
                    PortletException {  


     // do your stuff here

     }
```